# What type of paint is suitable over Cempolay Ultra Strong concrete leveler?

Tags: flooring, paint, garage, self-leveling-concrete

I've leveled my garage floor using Cempolay Ultra Strong and the instructions state "Suitable for use on domestic garage floors 
prior to over coating with a suitable floor paint."

Would anyone have any insight into a "suitable floor paint"? I have emailed manufacturers but they have not responded.

I guess I would like the paint to be a red an durable enough to last a few years of a car and motorcycle coming in and out of the garage.

No need to name brands, just the ingredients I should be looking out for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

2 part epoxy paints are the toughest for garage floors. The floor paint in 1 can really has not held up well for those I know that have used it. The 1 part stuff pulls up where the tires sit. I had a 3 bay shop with a 33' motor home in 1 bay and 3500 diesel truck in another and the floor looked great after 8-10 years when I sold the place. some of the big box stores carry 2 part but I am not sure if it comes in red, I only remember blue and gray.

Comment: Might be possible to add tint to the gray... Or order colors not usually stocked in the local stores.. Check w/ manufacturer.